# Allow plugins in nodejs application / electron

Tags: node.js, plugins, electron

I am creating an application which further down the line, will allow users to create plugins for it. I am new in regards of plugin development and do not know how to properly search for examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

As it is this is far too broad -- there's no actual question to it, only a statement. If you'd like a useful answer try editing to include a question which we can attempt to answer.

Here's a couple open-source Electron-based projects that support plugins which should help you get started, or at least give you an idea what to look around for/start building:

- [a game editor](https://github.com/fireball-x/editor-framework)
- [electron-updater](https://github.com/EvolveLabs/electron-updater)